# "Не удалось обработать пакет" при запуске Apk

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, apk

**Алгоритм:**

1. Get методом приложение получает Apk файл
2. Файл сохраняется в памяти устройства
3. Инициализируется и запускается Intent

**Ожидаемый результат:**

Установка приложения из Apk файла

**Фактический результат:**

Появление окна "Не удалось обработать пакет"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же нет логов ошибок, при появление данного окна.

**Код:**

```
val myReq: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.GET,
            FILE_URL,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                    installUpdate(response)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error -> ${it?.message} | ${it?.networkResponse?.statusCode} ")

            }
        )

private fun installUpdate(it: String) {

     val FILE_NAME = "foobar.apk"

    val file = File(
    context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
    FILE_NAME
    )

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile()
    }

    file.writeBytes(it.toByteArray())
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    val data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
        file
    );

    intent.setDataAndType(data, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    context.startActivity(intent)


}
```

Буду рада любой помощи!

Comment: а вручную тот apk ставится нормально? может он просто несовместим.

Comment: В ручную apk ставится без проблем.

Comment: а запрос на установку из неизвестных источников в манифест прописан? какая версия андроид?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй таким образом, но я не уверен сработает, ли

```
installUpdate("https://foo.bar/")

private fun installUpdate(url: String) {

    val FILE_NAME = "foobar.apk"

    try (final InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream()) {

        val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+FILE_NAME

        Path outputFile = Paths.get(path);

        Files.copy(in, outputFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        val file = File(path)

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    val data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
        file
    );

    intent.setDataAndType(data, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    context.startActivity(intent)

}
```